# Deserializing nested XML into classes

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I have the following XML:

```
<Root>
   <EventSet>
      <Event>
         <id>12345</id>
         <rant>
            <localTime>
               <dst>true</dst>
               <time>7/2/2012 14:30</time>
            </localtime>
            <randomRant>
               <random>to illustrate point</random>
               <rant>help me!</rant>
            </randomRant>
         </rant>
      </Event>
      <Event>/*another event*/</Event>
      <Event>/*another event*/</Event> //etc
   </EventSet>
</Root>
```

I want to map this to:

```
[Serializable] 
public class Events  
{      
     public List<Event> events { get; set; } 
}  

[Serializable] 
public class Event 
{      
    public int id { get; set; }      
    public Rant rant { get; set; } //this is where I get confused
}
```

***QUESTION**: How do I serialize the tags within `<rant>`? Do I continue to make serialized classes of the parent until the child tags have no children? For example, below:*

```
[Serializable] 
public class Rant
{      
    public LocalTime localTime { get; set; }      
    public RandomRant randomRant { get; set; }
}

[Serializable] 
public class LocalTime
{      
    public bool dst { get; set; }
    public DateTime time { get; set; }
}

[Serializable] 
public class RandomRant
{      
    public string random { get; set; }
    public string rant { get; set; }
}
```

*Or is there a better approach?*

**EDIT:** A given `event` has one and only one `id`, and one and only one `rant`.  For the sake of my question, assume my types are valid. I am looking to deserialize nested XML into an object.

Comment: Are localTime and utcTime arrays or single values?

Comment: I am not sure what your question is. Are you trying to store a single DateTime in two formats, local and UTC? Or do the two DateTimes represent different values (not just TimeZone difference)? Erick

Comment: I changed my XML. Nothing to do with `DateTime` formats. I want to know how to deserialize into an object from XML with nested tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example you gave seems fine to me.
As for the time values, the date format in your example is not compatible with xsd:dateTime, so you can't just do

```
public DateTime time { get; set; }
```

This will not be serialized. Although you can hack this using a custom XmlSerializer, a more simple approach is to use:

```
[XmlIgnore]
public DateTime _time {
    get { return DateTime.ParseExact(this.time, "MM/dd/YYYY HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);} // or use some specific culture here.
}

[XmlElement]
public string time { get; set; }
```

UPDATE:
`public List<Event> events` will be de/serialized as:

```
<events>
    <Event></Event>
    <Event></Event>
    <Event></Event>
</events>
```

You can make it as:

```
[XmlElement("Event")]
public List<Event> events {get; set}
```

and it will be serialized as

```
    <Event></Event>
    <Event></Event>
    <Event></Event>
```

without  wrapper.

Or, using:

```
[XmlArray("EventSet")]
[XmlArrayItem("Event")]
public List<Event> events {get; set}
```

will be serialized as described in the example

```
<EventSet>
    <Event></Event>
    <Event></Event>
</EventSet>
```

And of course the root element:

```
[XmlRoot("Root")]
public class RootElement{
    [XmlArray("EventSet")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Event")]
    public List<Event> events {get; set}
}
```

Comment: I am using a proprietary time format and generalized it for my question. I am looking to deserialize into an object from XML with nested tags. Let's assume everything is valid for the sake of my question.

Comment: Okay, I've just updated the answer with some examples on how to de/serialize the array elements. Except the arrays - your code seems fine to deserialize this xml.